# Find duplicate in a list (not compare 2 lists), and show them on a second column based of prior appeareance

Tags: excel

In a column (A) i have a list:

```
car
banana
apple
airplane
ticket
car
ticket
.....
```

In the second column (B) I need to detect all duplicates from A, if the keyword already appeared in the list then I should display it on the same row, if not to display n/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `VLOOKUP` with a variable range:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:A1,1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can select the column and use the pivot table and now you have a new table with the count of the data. then you should use the filter for remove the no duplicated value.